# Yii CDetailView translate sub-property

Tags: php, yii, translation

```
<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
'data' => $model,
'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width:425px; float:left; margin-right:20px; word-break:break-all', 'class' => 'detail-view table table-striped table-condensed'),
'attributes' => array(
    'id',
    'name',
    'street',
    'housenumber',
    'zipcode',
    'city',
    array(
        'label' => Yii::t('api', 'Country'),
        'name' => Yii::t('api', 'country.name'),
    ),
),
));
?>
```

I want to translate the values for the attributes label and name in the array for the columns. 
But it only translate the label and not the name.

Can someone tell me, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name` is the column name in the database, I think you want to adjust `value`, try this:

```
'label' => Yii::t('api', 'Country'),
'name' => 'country.name', //in reality you don't need this since you are setting the value
'value' => Yii::t('api', $model->country->name),
```

Comment: Sorry, but this answer does not work. Yii's translation mechanism can not translate dynamic content. So in the above you can not have `$model->country->name` inside `Yii::t()`. What should Yii put into the translation catalogue for this variable? To manage DB content translation you need another solution. There are some translation behaviors out there, that might help you.